# Devolver por $POST el usuario seleccionado

Tags: php

Tengo intención de que cada vez que seleccione un operario al darle al submit los datos se enviaran por POST por tanto luego quiero que aparezca en el select el operario seleccionado.

Adjunto código:

**PHP**

```
  <select name='operari_sel' id='operari_sel'>
    <option value='default'>Selecciona un trabajador</option>";
             while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $id_operari=$row['tre_operario'];
                $nom_treballador = $row['tre_nom']." ".$row['tre_cognom'];
                echo "<option value='$id_operari'>".$row["tre_operario"]." - ".$row["tre_nom"]." ".$row["tre_cognom"]."</option>";
              }
    echo "</select>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagino que quieres algo así:

```
<select name='operari_sel' id='operari_sel'>
    <option value='default'>Selecciona un trabajador</option>";
             while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $id_operari=$row['tre_operario'];
                $selected = ($_POST['operari_sel'] == $id_operari) ? 'selected' : '' ;
                $nom_treballador = $row['tre_nom']." ".$row['tre_cognom'];
                echo "<option value='$id_operari' ".$selected.">".$row["tre_operario"]." - ".$row["tre_nom"]." ".$row["tre_cognom"]."</option>";
              }
    echo "</select>";
```

**Explicación de los cambios:**

Si el dato `operari_sel` es mandado por `$_POST` al mismo archivo *PHP* u otro, pero que muestra el mismo `select`, podemos recuperar ese dato y compararlo, dentro del bucle que vuelve a crear las opciones,  con el valor de la fila itinerada en cada ciclo. Y en caso coincidente procedemos a agregar el atributo `selected` en el `<option>` en curso de la iteración.

Para ello usamos esta expresión con *operador ternario*:

```php
$selected = ($_POST['operari_sel'] == $id_operari) ? 'selected' : '' ;
```

donde asignamos a la nueva variable `$selected` o bien un string `'selected'` (que seria el atributo) o bien nada `''`.

Esa expresión no es más que una reducción de la siguiente:

```php
if ($_POST['operari_sel'] == $id_operari) {
    $selected = 'selected';
} else {
    $selected = '';
}
```

que viene a ser lo mismo, pero con el *operador ternario* (`?:`) queda muy bien reducida y también se puede comprender si sabemos como funcionan.

El siguiente paso es incluir esa nueva variable en el `<option>` en cada ciclo, y lo hacemos así:

```php
echo "<option value='$id_operari' ".$selected.">".$row["tre_operario"]." - ".$row["tre_nom"]." ".$row["tre_cognom"]."</option>";
```

De esta forma si no hay coincidencia no se verá nada nuevo en el *html* de salida, pero si la hay aparecerá el `selected` y eso obligará al `select` a mostrarlo seleccionado durante su aparición. Cabe cedir que también se podria haber usado `selected="selected"` en su lugar, pues seria mas *XML* compatible, pero eso ya es otro tema y va a gustos (a mi me gusta más pues pasa mejor ciertos tests).

Comment: Funciona master eres un crack!, explícame