# Colocar como valor predeterminado en un select, un valor de base de datos MYSQL en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, array, html-select

Estoy haciendo un programa donde necesito poner en un `<select>` los períodos (en años) que están registrados activos en una base de datos  *mysql*.

Lo que necesito es dejar como *opción predeterminada* en el campo, en lugar de que diga "Elegir período". Debo dejar **el registro más reciente**, es decir, si tengo años del 2010 al 2020, debo dejar el 2020 como *predeterminado*.

Este es mi código:

```php
<option selected>Elegir período </option> <!--Hay que dejar como preestablecido la opción actual-->
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('servername', 'username', 'password', 'database');
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
$sql_s = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM database.periodos WHERE status='activado' ORDER BY anio");
while ($row_s = $sql_s->fetch_array()){
    $ID_periodo = $row_s['anio'];
    $periodo = $row_s['anio'];
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $ID_periodo; ?>"><?php echo $periodo; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: Mírate esta respuesta a ver si te ayuda, y sino avisa y miro de explicartelo más acorde con tu caso, pero alli tienes todo lo que necesitas saber si lees bien la respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/513866/devolver-por-post-el-usuario-seleccionado/513870#513870

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para conseguir lo que deseas, dada tu consulta SQL actual, tan solo hace falta que agreges el atributo `selected` en el elemento `<option>` que coincida con tu intención, la cual no queda claro cual és del todo porque comentas dos posibles comportamientos, uno en la pregunta:

```
Debo dejar el registro más reciente
```

Y otro dentro del código, en este comentario que aparece:

```
<!--Hay que dejar como preestablecido la opción actual-->
```

Por otro lado, si no deseas que aparezca la opción `Elegir período` como predeterminada, simplemente puedes eliminarla tal cual, y de este modo tambien se eliminará el atributo `selected` que ahora mismo tiene. Solo puede haber un atributo `selected` entre todos los elementos `option` que componen un elemento `select`.  Si hubiera dos o más, prevalece el último en ser asignado.

Como ejemplo, suponiendo que tu intención final fuera la expresada en la pregunta, es decir, *"Dejar el registro más reciente"*, dada la consulta actual, la cual nos ordenará los resultados en el orden ascendente de los años (de menor a mayor), tan solo debes agregar el atributo `selected` en la última iteración del bucle **`while`** existente.

Para ello podrias hacer algo asi:

```
<!-- esto lo dejo comentado para que se vea que lo he eliminado
<option selected>Elegir período </option>
-->
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('servername', 'username', 'password', 'database');
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
$sql_s = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM database.periodos WHERE status='activado' ORDER BY anio");
$numero_de_filas = $sql_s->num_rows;
$contador = 0;
while ($row_s = $sql_s->fetch_array()){
    $contador++;
    $ID_periodo = $row_s['anio'];
    $periodo = $row_s['anio'];
    if($contador == $numero_de_filas) {
        $selected = "selected";
    } else {
        $selected = "";
    }
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $ID_periodo; ?>" <?php echo $selected ?>><?php echo $periodo; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
```

Fíjate en estos cambios:

1. Se ha agregado esta línea antes del bucle:

```
$numero_de_filas = $sql_s->num_rows;
```

que nos asignará el valor del número de filas resultantes de la consulta a la variable `$numero_de_filas` gracias a la función `num_rows`, tal com explica su [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.num-rows.php).

2. Después se ha inicializado la variable `$contador` con un valor de 0 antes del bucle, que iremos incrementando en uno en cada iteración del bucle después:

```
$contador = 0;
```

3. Dentro del bucle incrementamos en 1 el valor de la variable `$contador`:

```
$contador++;
```

4. Hemos agregado este condicional en el bucle:

```
if($contador == $numero_de_filas) {
    $selected = "selected";
} else {
    $selected = "";
}
```

el cual comparará, en cada iteración o ciclo, los valores de las variables $contador y $numero_de_filas.  Si son coincidentes nos asignará el texto `"selected"` a la variable `$selected`. En caso contrario la dejará vacia, sin texto.
5) Y por último, hemos agregado la variable `$selected` al elemento `<option>` en cada iteración:

```
<option value="<?php echo $ID_periodo; ?>" <?php echo $selected ?>><?php echo $periodo; ?></option>
```

para que aparezca su valor resultado de la condición anterior.

Otro modo de reescribir todo tu código para hacerlo con menos líneas sería este:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('servername', 'username', 'password', 'database');
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
$sql_s = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM database.periodos WHERE status='activado' ORDER BY anio");
$numero_de_filas = $sql_s->num_rows;
$contador = 0;
while ($row_s = $sql_s->fetch_array()){
    $contador++;
    $selected = ($contador == $numero_de_filas) ? "selected": "";
    echo '<option value="'.$row_s['anio'].' '.$selected.'>'.$row_s['anio'].'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
```