# quiero que la etiqueta option se seleccione automáticamente con php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Necesito que me expliquen o me den un ejemplo.  Voy hacer  un apartado con php de editar pero no se hacer que la etiqueta `<option>` se coloque automáticamente dependiendo de lo que traiga de la base de datos.

Comment: Mírate esta respuesta y tan solo debes cambiar el condicional que veas alli por lo que quieras de tu base de datos:  https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/514610/263200

Comment: @ffflabs perdon por cuestionarte, pero por favor, se delicado con el tema de los votos negativos. Algunos nos los podemos tomar personal (o al menos, eso me pasó a mi).

Comment: Mi intención no es ser grosero sino hacerme cargo de mis votos negativos. Me parece mejor explicarlo, aunque suene brusco y alguien me tome algo de animosidad, que dejar un voto anónimo sin una causa explícita.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

esto es muy fácil, solamente haces una consulta a la tabla que necesitas, ejemplo "tipo de usuario" y luego haces un ciclo `while`. Dejo el código solo para que reemplaces valores:

```php
$ConsultaTipoUsuario = "SELECT * FROM `Tbl_T/U`";

$ListaTipo = mysqli_query($con, $ConsultaTipoUsuario);

<div class="form-outline mb-3">

   
    <select name="Tipo" class="form-select form-select-lg mb-3" id="TipoU">
    <?php
        while ($datos = $ListaTipo->fetch_array()) {
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $datos["ID_Tipo"] ?>"><?php echo $datos["Nombre/TipoUsuario"] ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
    
<?php echo $CorreoValidar; ?>
</div>
```